# How to require multiple modules in a single statement?

Tags: module, lua, wildcard, package, require

I want to require several Lua modules at once, similar the to the asterisk signifier from  Java (`import java.awt.*`). This the structure I organized my modules in subdirectories:

```
<myapp>
 -- calculations
    -- calc1
    -- calc2
    -- calc3
 -- helper
     -- help1
     -- help2
     -- print
          --graphprinter
          --matrixprinter
```

My client requires each module of a subpath:

```
 local graphprinter = require("myapp.helper.print.graphprinter")
 local matrixprinter = require("myapp.helper.print.matrixprinter")
```

I would prefer an automatic multi-require, which derives the local table names from the module path and requires a whole subpath at once. This could be the format: `require("myapp.helper.print.*")`. Automatically the local table names should be created for each module of the subdirectory, so that there isn't any difference as I would have required them module by module.

Comment: Lua does not have the ability to get list of all files in a folder, so you can not get list of modules.  But you can write a script to get list of modules by issuing shell commands with `io.popen"ls..."` and then `require()` all modules found.

Comment: There also has recomentation to not create global variables in modules. So there no easy way to get module value even if you can load all of them. So may be just make separate file wich do load all needed values and returns loaded values as table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [`env`](https://github.com/Okahyphen/env) *partially* achieves what you are looking for, though it is far from perfect.

It allows for grouped / named imports, with some caveats - the main one being you must manually manage your environments. In addition, you'll need to write index files (default `init.lua`, unless you write a custom path set), since it is intended for use with modules that export tables.

Here's a bit of an example. First we need to properly set up our file structure.

```
 -- main.lua
 -- calculations /
    -- calc1.lua
    -- calc2.lua
    -- calc3.lua
    -- init.lua
 -- helper /
     -- print /
          -- init.lua
          -- graphprinter.lua
          -- matrixprinter.lua
```

The index files, which are slightly tedious:

```
-- calculations/init
return {
    calc1 = require 'calculations.calc1',
    calc2 = require 'calculations.calc2',
    calc3 = require 'calculations.calc3'
}
```

and

```
-- helpers/print/init
return {
    graphprinter = require 'helper.print.graphprinter',
    matrixprinter = require 'helper.print.matrixprinter'
}
```

Inside your main file. The major caveat shows itself quickly, you must use the function returned by requiring `'env'` to override your local environment. Passing no arguments will create a clone of your current environment (preserving `require`, etc.).

```
-- main.lua
local _ENV = require 'env' () -- (see notes below)
```

The new environment will be given an [`import`](https://github.com/Okahyphen/env#import) function, which takes a single argument, a string represent the *path* or *module name* to import into the current environment. The return value is a transient table that can be used to further alter the environment state.

```
import 'helper/print' :use '*'
import 'calculations' :use '*'
```

One of the functions on the transient table is `:use`, which either takes a table indicating which values to pull from the required table, or the string `'*'`, which indicates you want *all* values from the required table placed in your current environment

```
print(matrixprinter, graphprinter) --> function: 0x{...} function: 0x{...} (or so)
```

The final caveat is that all the paths you've seen are reliant on the [`cwd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) being the same as the one that holds `main.lua`. `lua myapp/main.lua` will fail loudly, unless you place your sub modules in a static location, and adjust `package.path` / `import.paths` correctly.

Seems like a lot of work to avoid a couple of lines of `require` statements.

---

*Disclaimer: I wrote [`env`](https://github.com/Okahyphen/env) as a bit of an experiment.*

*Note that `import` does not currently support the `.` syntax (you need to use your OS path delimiter), or proper exploding of tables into table chains. I have a bit of a patch in the works that addresses this.*

*Lua 5.2+ uses `_ENV` to override local environments. For Lua 5.1, you'll need to use [`setfenv`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv).*

---

As mentioned above, Lua has no real notion of directories. To really do what you want (with less overhead), you'll need to write your own custom module loader, environment handler, and likely make use of a module like [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) to reliably 'automatically' load all files in a directory.

---

TL;DR:

- This is a tricky topic.
- There's nothing built into the language to make this easy.
- You'll need to write something custom.
- There will always be drawbacks.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just write an `init.lua` file for each folder that requires all the other libraries?

For example, in calculations you write a file that contains

```
return {
  calc1 = require "calc1";
  calc2 = require "calc2";
  calc3 = require "calc3";
}
```

Then you can just write `calculations = require "calculations"` and it will automatically load `calculations.calc<1-3>`

This can be done for the entire directory structure, and `require "helper"` can call `require "help1"` which in turn calls `require "print"` and in the end you can find your functions in `helper.help1.print.<function>`

Short explanation of how this works: When you run `require "library"` lua will either try to include a file called `library.lua` or the file `init.lua` located in a `library` directory. This is also the reason why you do `require "dir.lib"` instead of `require "dir/lib"`; because, if done right, when you just `require "dir"` it will return a table that contains the field `lib`, so you would access it as `dir.lib.<function>`.